# CommandButton action triggering despite validation errors

Tags: validation, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a page which contains `<input type="text">` fields which have the `required="true"` attribute set. I also have a save button which submits the form.

Unfortunately, the form submits even if the `required="true"` field is left empty.

This is my current code:

```
<s:decorate template="layout/edit.xhtml" id="decAQty">
    <ui:define name="label">Actual Qty Received</ui:define>
    <h:inputText
        value="#{tktReceivingInfoHome.instance.actualReceivedQty}"
        required="true" id="txtAQty"
        converterMessage="Not a valid Quantity">
        <a:ajax event="blur" render="txtAcTotal,decAQty"
            listener="#{returnsReceivingManager.setActualTotal}" />

    <h:messages id="error" style="display:none" />
    </h:inputText>

<a:commandButton id="btnSave"
    action="#{returnsReceivingManager.checkQtyDiff}" value="Save"
    render="decSQty,decScQty,decRtvQty,addForm,decAQty,decRecdDate,decRecWH,decErrorRMA,decErrorRTV,decReason,decStatusRMA,decStatusRTV,decPriority,decResolution"
    oncomplete="#{returnsReceivingManager.rmaInfo.qtyDiff!=0 ? '#{rich:component(\'addPanel\').show();' : 'callSave();'}"
    onclick="showProgressBar()" />
<a:jsFunction action="#{returnsReceivingManager.save}"
    oncomplete="hideProgressBar()" name="callSave" />
```

When I click the save button, I can see the message pop up indicating that the value is required, but it then disappears and gives me a message stating that the transaction is failed.

In other words, it appears that the page is being submitted twice. I'd love any suggestions that the community can provide about how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Both the command button and the input text are in the same form?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment validation is only triggered on leaving the `txtAQty` field (blur event). That's why you see the error message. What happens next is the click on the save button, which performs rerendering of some fields, but without processing (including validation) of any field. That's why the error disappears.

You should add the `process` attribute to the commandButton with values listing at least the `txtAQty` field (but even better also all the other fields which you are rerendering)